# Show that $\cos(\sqrt{z}) = z$ has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm working through past complex analysis qualifying exams to study for my own upcoming exam next month. I'd like to know whether or not my answer is correct and complete (and if not, what the correct/complete proof would be). Thanks!

**Problem:**

Show that the equation $\cos(\sqrt{z}) = z$ has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.

**Solution:**

We begin with the exponential form of $\cos(z)$ and let $z=re^{i\theta}$.

We know that $\cos{z} = \frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2} = \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$, thus $\cos{\sqrt{z}} = \frac{\sqrt{z}+(\sqrt{z})^{-1}}{2}$ and the equation becomes

$$
\sqrt{z}+(\sqrt{z})^{-1} = 2z \quad \implies \quad z + 1 = 2z^{3/2}
$$

Squaring both sides yields
$$
(z+1)^2 = 2z^3 \quad \implies \quad z^2 + 2z + 1 = 2z^3 \quad \implies \quad 2z^3 - z^2 - 2z - 1 = 0.
$$

We can factor this into
$$
(z-1)(4z^2 + 3z + 1) = 0
$$

and thus it's clear that one solution is $z = 1$. However, in the complex plane, we have
$$
z = re^{i\theta} = 1 \quad \implies \quad i\theta = \ln(\frac{1}{r}) \quad \implies \quad \theta = -i\ln(\frac{1}{r})
$$

Since the complex logarithm is an infinitely value function, we have that there are infinitely many solutions to the given equation.

Comment: $\cos z\color{blue}{=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2}\color{red}{\neq(z+z^{-1})/2}$.

Comment: Here's a question... how do you define "infinitely many"?  Presumably you mean distinct. But what constitutes a distinct solution?  Is $1e^{i0\pi}$ distinct from $1e^{i2\pi}$?  These are distinct by some measure, equivalent by others.

Comment: @SquishyRhode Good question, and to be honest I'm not super clear on this myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos z$ is not $\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$ and $1$ is definitely not a root of $\cos \sqrt z=z$ since $\cos (\pm 1) \ne 1$.

The way to do it (in an elementary way without Picard etc) is to note that $\cos \sqrt z=\sum (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{(2n)!}$ is entire and behaves like an exponential $\frac{e^{\sqrt r}}{2}$ for $z=\pm ir, r >0 $ large, while it always satisfies $$|\cos \sqrt z|=|\sum (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{(2n)!}| \le \sum \frac{|z|^n}{(2n)!} \le e^{\sqrt {|z|}}$$

So now if $\cos \sqrt z=z$ has finitely many solutions, it follows that $g(z)=\cos \sqrt z-z=P(z)e^{h(z)}$ with $P$ a polynomial having same (finitely many) roots (with same multiplicity) as $g$ (and where $P=1$ if $g$ has no roots) and $h$ entire.

Then since $Pe^h=g$ it follows by taking absolute values and logarithms that $\Re h(z) \le c\sqrt {|z|}$ for $|z|$ large enough, hence $h$ must be constant (by Caratheodory-Borel for example) and that is impossible since for $z=ir$ we have that $g$ grows much faster than $P$ for large enough $r$ by the above

Same proof shows that $\cos \sqrt z-Q(z)$ has infinitely many roots for any polynomial $Q$ (including constants) and with a bit more care one can show that the number of roots of modulus at most $R$ is of the order $\sqrt R$ for large enough $R$ (basically from Jensen theorem)

Comment: Oh my... this is a bit embarrassing. It seems I had been looking at this stuff too long yesterday and got myself all turned around (*facepalm*). I somehow went from $\cos(\theta) = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2} = \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$ when dealing with a contour $z = e^{i\theta}$ to complete error very quickly. THANK YOU for your help. I had actually started down the series expansion route but then didn't know what to do with it. I'm working my way through understanding your solution now.

Comment: You mentioned that the above is the elementary method without using Picard. Would it be a more direct route to use Picard?

Comment: maybe not Picard directly in this case ($\cos \sqrt z-z$ has real coefficients so any real value including zero, could be an omitted one) but the theory of order as $\cos \sqrt z-z$ has order $1/2$ and such functions have infinitely many zeroes by general theory as only functions of finite integral orders (or those of infinite order) can omit values, so have no (or finitely many) zeroes